# OOMMF: simulate stray field for micro magnets

Tags: simulation, physics

I'd like to simulate the stay fields of micro magnets with different geometries. The goal is to get the shape of the stray field and the value of the strength of the field at a specific position. I already created a MIF file and run the mmDisp, so I can see the shape. But I'd like to get numbers instead of a graphical solution. In the manual of OOMMF, I can't find the solution. Is there any tutorial for that or do you have sone ideas ?

Thanks a lot !

I created a MIF file and got a graphical field, but only inside the magnet without values.